# How can I access the cancel event on an ios OTA install?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to either access the cancel or install events from safari and/or stop the browser from minimizing once the install begins? I would like to send the user to a thank you page once they install the application, but only on a successful install, not a cancel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **no**. This is unfortunately not possible.

What you might consider is presenting a special screen with a *Thank You* label, etc in the app when user launches it for the first time.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"AppHasAlreadyLaunched"])
    {
        // app already launched
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"AppHasAlreadyLaunched"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        // This is the first launch ever
        // Show special view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've meant a successful installation of your app, as there's no way to determine if iOS has been updated OTA (e.g. from 7 to 7.1). You can route them to Safari (using a simple UIApplication method) once the app was opened-

`[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourpagehere.com"]];`